# Boldfacing Plot Legend with words, numbers, and symbols in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering how to **boldface** the entire phrase: "**95% CI: [number 1 , number 2 ]**" as a legend in my plot below? (**Note:** *"number 1"* and *"number 2"* are specified in my code below).

**Here is my R code** which requires a fix:

```
plot(1:10,ty="n",bty="n")

legend("topleft", legend=bquote(paste(bold("95% CI: [ ", .(round(.4432, 3)), 
", " , .(round(.0034, 3))," ]"))), 
                 bty="n", inset=c(0,.03))
```

P.S. If I omit the `bold()` part from the code, the entire phrase shows normally, but I loose the **bolding** effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options/workarounds:

1. You can `bold()` each literal string individually, but I don't know how to bold the dynamic portions (e.g., `.(round(.4432,3))`). This would look like:

   ```
   plot(1:10,ty="n",bty="n")
   legend("topleft", legend=bquote(paste(bold("95% CI: [ "), .(round(.4432, 3)), 
                                         bold(", ") , .(round(.0034, 3)),
                                         bold(" ]"))), 
          bty="n", inset=c(0,.03))
   ```

   The numbers are not bold.
2. With this label/legend, you don't actually need `bquote`, so you can use the `text.font` option of `legend` to bold the whole string:

   ```
   plot(1:10,ty="n",bty="n")
   legend("topleft", legend=paste("95% CI: [ ", round(.4432, 3),
                                  ", " , round(.0034, 3),
                                  " ]"),
          bty="n", inset=c(0,.03), text.font=2)
   ```

   The disadvantage with this is that you are you able to use math symbols.

The `text.font` is a `legend`-specific argument for the more-generic `font` parameter, found in [`?par`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html):

```
 'font' An integer which specifies which font to use for text.  If
      possible, device drivers arrange so that 1 corresponds to
      plain text (the default), 2 to bold face, 3 to italic and 4
      to bold italic.  Also, font 5 is expected to be the symbol
      font, in Adobe symbol encoding.  On some devices font
      families can be selected by 'family' to choose different sets
      of 5 fonts.
```

Comment: highly appreciated.